# ElasticSearch - Static Mapping vs Dynamic Mapping when using templates

Tags: templates, elasticsearch, mapping

I have let my system run with dynamic mapping for a while.
It created a huge index form all of my entity data (current and history )
Many fields that I wouldn't like to index are being index.

So, I thought to change it to static mapping.
This way I would set only thte fields I need, My problem is that:

1. The index is still very big, but that's ok.
2. In dynamic mapping a lot of definitions are now written in one place - 
   the template (using matcher).
   In static mapping I will not be able to define it in one place.

Changing a behavior in static mapping will require me to change it in multiple places.

Is there a way to apply a template behaviour in static mapping?
When is it considered a good practice to use static mapping?

Comment: As I said in your other question on SO :-), there is no such thing as a template for a static mapping. You need to make the changes one by one manually.

Comment: And if, still, not convinced: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/12358